# How to implement a Android bluetooth paring without pop up a dialog to get a user permition?

Tags: android, bluetooth

These days , i implement a blue tooth paring function on android platform,say in details:
The master device is Google TV(3.2), the slave device is blue tooth keyboard,both are HID device.
 The Keyboard can be easily put in to discoverable status, When the TV bootup first time ,In TV setup guide, i need to let the tv paring with keyboard,
As you know, in generall, enable bluetooth on TV side we need get the user permition, then can connect.Then my question happend is that i don't want to pop up a dialog to get permition, is there some body can tell me how to do ?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know you'll be pairing to the right device?

Comment: the safe way is to use MAC addr

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple way - in the Android code tree, in `external\bluetooth\bluez\src\device.c`:

```
/* If our IO capability is NoInputNoOutput use medium security
 * level (i.e. don't require MITM protection) else use high
 * security level */
if (capability == 0x03)
    sec_level = BT_IO_SEC_MEDIUM;
else
    sec_level = BT_IO_SEC_HIGH;


//david10000 add 
if (device_is_david10000_BTDEV(device)) {
    sec_level = BT_IO_SEC_MEDIUM;
}
```

This means  we can low level the security to let your special device connect automatically.

Another way  is you can program it to auto fill the  passkey/pin etc. when you get the Android  pair request.
If you have this problem, try this, it works for me.